# How to share POJO between GAE and Android app when using Objectify

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have created a separate module where i store POJO and use them in GAE Cloud Endpoints module as well as in Android App.

I want to store one of the objects in GAE Datastore. Now to mark this class as objectify i need to use annotations to identify Entity and Id. This would mean that my POJO Module would now need to import objectify jar. And I don't want to carry them into my Android app.

How should I go about it? Should I just import objectify stuff into POJO module? Or is there a workaround that objectify to be imported only into GAE module

Answer (score 1):

Once you generate the endpoints for Android or any other platform it will create a library for your Android application, that will be the only thing you have to import in your Android project. 
The library will have a model without that information.

You have a good example of Android app using endpoints here: 
https://github.com/udacity/conference-central-android-app

Comment: Well, you could. I noticed it compiled only the fields which my Java app was using.